# Excel vba convert cell value in dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, textbox, date-format, vba

I have a problem with date value in excel using vba.
I mae a userform that inseret date and other data. When i push the button it insert the date into a cell in a sheet. My problem is that when it copy the date in the textbox it copy it in mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub ins_stampa_btn_Click()

' FUNZIONALITA' EVENTO BOTTONE "INSERISCI IN STAMPA" DI INSERIMENTO PER LA STAMPA DELLE SPEDIZIONI
' PER DATA, FORNITORE, CORRIERE E MERCE

' CONTROLLO SE IL TEXTBOX DATA E' VUOTO O NON E' UNA DATA
If data_arr_txt = "" Or Not IsDate(data_arr_txt) Then
    MsgBox ("Inserire una Data di Spedizione valida")
    Exit Sub
End If

' CONTROLLO SE IL TEXTBOX DATA E' UNA DATA CONVERTIRLO IN FORMATO ITALIANO
If IsDate(data_arr_txt.Value) Then

    data_arr_txt.Value = Format(data_arr_txt.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If

MsgBox (data_arr_txt.Value)
lastAddress = lastCell("ORDINI SPEDITI", "A") ' ULTIMA CELLA PIENA DELLA COLONNA A

' COPIA DEI DATI INSERITI NELLA FORM STAMPASPED NEL FOGLIO STAMPA SPEDIZIONI
Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).Value = Format(CDate(data_arr_txt.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Value = fornitore_cbx.Value
Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(2, -1).Value = corriere_txt.Value
Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(2, -1).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(3, -1).Value = merce_txt.Value
Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(3, -1).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

In another sheet i made a similar userform and it copy the date as i want.
Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Use Clng() and try like this... data_arr_txt.Value = Format(CLng(data_arr_txt.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: Try to save the date value in a variable after you have checked if it is a date and then try to convert. In the line "MsgBox (data_arr_txt.Value)" what is shown in the messageBox?

Comment: In the msgbox it return the right date in the format dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: What language is your excel? italian or english?

Comment: My Excel is in Greek language

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried using Sixthsenxes solution?

Comment: What is this solution? I don't  know it

Comment: data_arr_txt.Value = Format(CLng(data_arr_txt.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your value to a `Date` variable before storing it in worksheet.

```
Dim temp_date as Date
...
temp_date = data_arr_txt.Value
Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).Value = temp_date
```

Comment: It Works! I haven't thought about this.Thank you very much

Comment: It should be done also in that way when you want to get a date from worksheet and store it in some vba variable. Always make this variable `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub ins_stampa_btn_Click()

    ' FUNZIONALITA' EVENTO BOTTONE "INSERISCI IN STAMPA" DI INSERIMENTO PER LA STAMPA DELLE SPEDIZIONI
    ' PER DATA, FORNITORE, CORRIERE E MERCE

    Dim wsSS as Sheet
    Set wsSS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("STAMPA SPEDIZIONI")
    Dim rangeSS as Range
    Set rangeSS = wsSS.Range("C1048576")
    Dim temp_date as Date

    ' CONTROLLO SE IL TEXTBOX DATA E' VUOTO O NON E' UNA DATA
    If data_arr_txt = "" Or Not IsDate(data_arr_txt) Then
        MsgBox ("Inserire una Data di Spedizione valida")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' CONTROLLO SE IL TEXTBOX DATA E' UNA DATA CONVERTIRLO IN FORMATO ITALIANO
    If IsDate(data_arr_txt.Value) Then
        temp_date = Format(data_arr_txt.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If

    lastAddress = lastCell("ORDINI SPEDITI", "A") ' ULTIMA CELLA PIENA DELLA COLONNA A

    ' COPIA DEI DATI INSERITI NELLA FORM STAMPASPED NEL FOGLIO STAMPA SPEDIZIONI
    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).Value = temp_date
    'rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Value = fornitore_cbx.Value
    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(2, -1).Value = corriere_txt.Value
    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(2, -1).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(3, -1).Value = merce_txt.Value
    rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(3, -1).Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

End Sub
```

If it doesn't work try to remove the comment on line `rangeSS.End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`