# date automatically converted to - instead of /

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have excel file. When I open this file in excel 2007 in windows 7 and when I enter date like 20/02/2019 then it automatically convert it to 20-02-2019.
Then this format interfere with vba program inside this file. IS there a way to stop this. Also I tried to convert format of cells to dd/mm/yyyy format. But it is also not available.
And is there a way to set / instead of - control panel or excel options. (may be like regional settings)

Comment: I know excel take date format from regional / format settings from windows.. how have you set this?

Comment: Didn't set anything in windows 7 or excel 2007. All are default settings. When I open the same file in win 10 and excel 2013 and enter date like 20/02/2019 then it doesn't change to 20-02-2019.

Comment: I don't understand why it would affect your program. Dates are a data type. Locale only affect how it is displayed.

Comment: I guess you have some code to analyze this string and get day, month and/or year of this date. Then, you should store your date in `Date` variable and use proper methods for this. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854684/excel-vba-convert-cell-value-in-dd-mm-yyyy/45855556#45855556) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205562/5722505).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the support. Yes the code break the date in to day, month and year and store in 3 cells. I think I can use methods in Egan Wolf's links.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer your looking for, but what I do when I need to change from the native format is to select the column that the date is entered that I need to format and change it to '*Custom*' and enter "*mm-dd-yyyy*" or whatever the case may be and can be separated by either "-" or "/".

The allowed entries for dates are:

Month: m = 1; mm = 01;  mmm = Jan;  mmmm = January

Day:  d = 1;  dd = 01

Year: yy" = 19;  yyyy = 2019